# Как получить Base64 код Steam Guard Mobile Authenticator

Tags: steam-web-api, steam

Как получить shared_secret используемый в Steam Guard Mobile Authenticator для генерации 5-ти значных кодов для последующего использования для входа в Steam от имени бота, при этом не имея телефона на IOS/Android и без различных эмуляторов Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения всех нужных данных, включая shared_secret, используйте [SteamDesktopAuthenticator](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamDesktopAuthenticator) С помощью этой программы вы можете либо получить все данный из привязанного Andoid телефона или можете привязать заново аккаунт.
Я используя эту программу получил доступы( shared_secret ) к более чем 400 аккаунтов steam